# Is it possible to change a term slug before being saved to the database?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, customization

We have a situation where we need to be able to do some categorization like this:

```
Root Category
  |-- Child Category
  |-- **Non-Unique Category**
Next Category
  |-- Next Level
        |-- **Non-Unique Category**
Another Category
  |-- **Non-Unique Category**
```

The problem we have found when creating categories is that the Slugs are unique. In our use-case, the slug doesn't get used in a URL so it could be a GUID for all we care, according to WordPress it just has to be unique.

If the slug is not unique WordPress throws an error saying that same name exists already. **How can we use a filter/action to change the term slug value before it commits to the database?**

**Bonus**: Can this be done with Custom taxonomies as well as builtins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pre_insert_term` filter to do just this

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_insert_term/